# How do I use variables in react native?

Tags: reactjs, mobile

```
var Square = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
  return (
      <View style={styles.square} />
  )
}
});
square: {
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  backgroundColor: 'red'
}
```

When I try to run this, I get an error "failed to load bundle".

```
var Card = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var card = this.props.card;

    return (
    <View style={styles.card}>
    <Text numberOfLines={2} ref="definition" style={styles.definition}>{card.definition}</Text>
    <Text numberOfLines={1} style={styles.chinese}>{this.props.simplified ? card.simplified : card.traditional}</Text>
    <Text ref="pinyin" numberOfLines={1} style={styles.pinyin}>{card.pinyin}</Text>
  </View>
 );
},
});
```

I'm trying to create something similar to this (code I found online), but I created a variation of this and it still does not run. Could someone explain to me what the problem is? Thank you.

Comment: Which version of React are you using?

Comment: Sorry. This is react native. It wouldn't let me put a tag for reactnative.

Comment: Which version of React Native are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is your only problem, but `React.createClass` is deprecated and has been removed from the latest version of React (React Native uses React).

You should use ES6 classes and functional, stateless components instead of `React.createClass`.

```
class Card extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Text>Class Component</Text>
    )
  }
}

function Square(props) {
  return (
    <Text>Functional Component</Text>
  )
}
```

If you still want to use `React.createClass`, you can, but it comes in its own package.

https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/26/react-v16.0.html